# Meaning of an English sentence on a Punjabi painting

Tags: meaning-in-context

> With the dawn sparrow's tweet, as bogged in woes  I trun and churn.

This sentence is written below a painting at my friend's house. The painting is Punjabi and depicts a woman using a machine to make butter or yogurt (not exactly sure which).

I know the meaning of the words (though I'm not sure about "trun"), but I don't know what the sentence means, especially the latter part. I'm guessing the first part of the sentence basically means "in the early morning".

Comment: The whole thing barely makes sense. The only way I can understand the _as_, is to make the whole sentence a scene-setter, that I would expect to be followed by more text: _as, bogged in woes, I turn and churn, [something happens]_.

Answer (score 2):

That is most likely to be a spelling mistake "turn" instead of "trun".

> With the dawn sparrow's tweet

Is the early morning, as you have said

> as bogged in woes I turn and churn.

She turns the machine and churns the butter to distract her from her woes or help her work out her woes. Alternatively, her woes could be caused by the activity itself.

Comment: and it rhymes better